Upgraded from Debian Jessie to Stretch but php -v still shows using 5.6.40?
The webpage at https://wiki.debian.org/PHP says Stretch should be using PHP 7 but after I upgraded from Jessie to Stretch typing:
php -v
at the command line says it's still using 5.6.40
How do I use the 7 version?
TIA!!

Please [edit] your question to show the output of command -v php and apt policy php.
